# Firewalld - Logging denied packets enabled - not logging

Tags: linux, security, iptables, firewall, firewalld

I am using Firewalld and the drop zone is the default zone with an interface assigned to the zone.

I then have rich rules to allow some traffic through the drop zone and I have enabled `firewall-cmd --set-log-denied=all`. I would of thought that this would log anything that attempts to connect to the server that doesn't come from the white-listed rich rule... but it won't log. I ran port scans against the server and the /var/log/messages doesn't show any of the denied ports logs.

However when I set the default zone to public and assign the interface to public, it does log denied packets when I run another port scan.

Why?

Comment: I noticed this question has been viewed a lot of times but there was no answer. However I can say I resolved the issue by updated to the latest release of Firewalld. The package version I was on at the time had a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to a bug as said in the comment. However, for those who are still having trouble to get the logging of firewall denial packets, the following approach worked for me:

The following worked with `firewalld` + `rsyslogd`

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/firewalld` and update the value for `LogDenied` to `all` (or as required)

```
LogDenied=all
```

restart firewalld

```
sudo systemctl restart firewalld
```

Alternatively, using the command line, one can execute the following command:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --set-log-denied all
```

This typically adds logging rules just before reject/drop rules in the firewall, something like:

```
LOG  all  --  anywhere   anywhere  LOG level warning prefix "IN_drop_DROP: "
LOG  all  --  anywhere   anywhere  LOG level warning prefix "FINAL_REJECT: "
```

Create a file named `/etc/rsyslog.d/custom_iptables.conf` and add the following statements to it:

```
:msg,contains,"_DROP" /var/log/iptables.log
& stop
:msg,contains,"_REJECT" /var/log/iptables.log
& stop
```

restart rsyslog

```
sudo systemctl restart rsyslog
```

Now the dropped and rejected packets will be logged to `/var/log/iptables.log`

Comment: Please follow as advised by #kondor6c in one of the answers.

Comment: In your `custom_iptables.conf`, you will likely also want to add a `& stop` line after the "_DROP" line, not just after the "_REJECT" line.  A `& stop` line only applies to the one line immediately above it.  As it's currently written, "_DROP" messages will get double-logged to both the `iptables.log` file and the main system log.

Answer (score 4):

Awesome job, this helped me go down the right path, I appreciate the post.

The only thing I noticed is that I believe that the location for `LogDenied=all` should be `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf` since `/etc/sysconfig/firewalld` is for startup command line options. Additionally the file for rsyslog might be better named with a .conf, sometimes default include statements might not look for a .log file.

Really good job VanagaS!

ref:
https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.conf.html

Comment: Thank you for the heads up!